If $f(g(x)) = x$, can I assume that $f(x) = g(x)$?
MEXT 2014, math B, Q1.3:

(3) If the functions $f(x) = \frac{3x+1}{2x+1}, g(x) = \frac{px+1}{2x-3}$ satisfy the relation $f(g(x)) = x (x \neq -\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$, then the constant p = $\square$

In this context, the argument - x - of $f(x)$ is $g(x)$, and the question says that that $f(x) = x$ for this argument.
Since the argument of $f(x)$ is essentially equal to $f(x)$, can I change the inside and the outside of the function? I mean:
$f(g(x)) = x \implies f(x) = g(x)$.
I don't want the answer, since I already know that $p = -1$, I want to know if this way of solving the question is correct or if it's just a coincidence. Let me know if I'm "assuming too much" or something.

Why would you think that?  If, say, $f(x)=\frac x2$ and $g(x)=2x$ we have $f\circ g(x)=x$.  If $f(x)=x-1$ and $g(x)=x+1$ we have $f\circ g(x)=x$ and so on.

Why would you assume that $\frac{3x+1}{2x+1}=\frac{-x+1}{2x-3}$?!

If $f(g(x))=x$ then under the right conditions $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ so you cannot say $f(x)=g(x)$
The right conditions are met by the functions you have given here.
Where I think the confusion has arisen is that some functions in the $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ family are their own inverse. If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ also - this is not typically the case though.
